Can I apply for a lost Pakistani passport without any information about the previous valid one?
I hold citizenship of Pakistan and two other countries, and have resided outside Pakistan for most of my life. When my family naturalized as citizens of one of the countries involved, about 20 years ago, my father disposed of our Pakistani passports, and we thus have no record of them as a family.
I would now like to apply for a new Pakistani passport, as due to recent changes in Saudi law, it is easier for me to perform the Hajj as a Pakistani citizen than as a Western one (despite the reverse being true for 'Umrah).
However, as there has already existed a Pakistani passport attached to my citizen number, I am required to apply for a lost passport replacement rather than a new passport (even though the existing passport in question was a child passport and expired many years ago). This is an issue, because in order to apply for such a replacement, I require, per the Consulate General of Pakistan in Chicago:

APPLICATION FOR LOST MACHINE READABLE PASSPORT/ MANUAL PASSPORT:
Applications for lost passport are processed after verification of particulars by the passport issuing authority.
[...]
REQUIREMENTS:
[...]

Photocopy/number of lost Pakistani Passport.


This is not possible for me to provide, as I don't have any photocopy, and I doubt my family has any record of the passport number either.
I called the Consulate General, and they insisted that one of these is necessary, but I wanted to ask here just in case: is there any possible method under Pakistani law that I can use to acquire a new passport in my circumstances?
If it helps, I do currently hold a valid, unexpired National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistanis (NICOP), which is considered proof of citizenship.

Can you just apply for a new/first passport? If your child passport was 20+ years ago, I highly doubt that the consulate will be aware of its existence either.

@lambshaanxy that certainly might be worth a shot, and is an option I was considering, but the problem is that I have to fly out to Chicago to get this done regardless, so I'd rather not take the risk of it being rejected due to them being aware of the passport's existence (making my trip unfruitful) if a better method might be available.

I'm not really sure what anyone here can tell you. You're going to have to apply for the new passport at your nearest consulate in Chicago, if they tell you a document is required, then I assume it is required. They're the ones who'll process the application.

This question asks about getting a UK passport number for an expired passport, and this is about Canadian passports. In both cases, there is not any simple or surefire way of finding out the number (you certainly can't just ask the government), so Pakistan may be no different. Applying for a new passport might be the best option.

@StuartF I'd say that given the response of the Pakistani Consulate General, applying for a new passport is the only option.
